# How can I remove ALL of someone's contributions to a project using git?

Tags: git

I am a contributor to a very old project presently in the process of relicensing. There are only about 30 contributors to the project, but it's almost ten years old at this point; Many of these people have moved on and I'm not sure I can find them all.

The project is presently using git for version control, and git has the full history from the CVS before.

In the event that I can't contact someone, we have to remove ALL of their work, and everything derived from that work. Is there a way to cause git to remove all of a person's commits, and any commit that touched the lines inserted by that person?

Comment: That is an ***incredibly*** drastic measure to take.  What if the commit touches an entire module, which was small but never needed to be updated since it performed its function correctly?

Comment: The license requires it. It makes me sick to think I have to destroy ten years of work because someone else ten years ago made a paperwork error (used GPL instead of LGPL, when we are a DLL plugin to a closed-source simulator) but such is the law.

Comment: This is pretty dangerous as I'm sure that removing the commit would be very destructive to the project. I don't know if you're using github/bitbucket/etc but maybe email them to see what your possibilities are as well?

Comment: It doesn't matter how destructive it is to the project, it's a legal issue. For the purposes of this question the user's contributions are poison, even a single character remaining in any form can be grounds for a lawsuit.

Comment: @Ryan:  At this point, the legal argument is perfectly valid and will may result in breakage, but is a perfectly understandable thing to have happen.

Comment: @Makoto I guess I didn't fully understand how serious it was so I was initially worried about the breakage but bc of the legal issue I understand.

Comment: @Ryan:  Don't worry, I was right there with you with my earlier remark.

Comment: BTW, "even a single character remaining..." is an exaggeration, ask any competent lawyer specializing in IP. If you copy the word "the" from a comment in GPLv3 code, does that make it a derived work and subject you to GPL requirements? No, there are limits. Its called de minimus. Also, the copied code must be expressive. For instance "const float PI = 3.1415;"? Thats a fact, not expressive, so also would be hard to make the claim of derived work off of that. Although where the line can be drawn is vague, so you don't want to get close to it, so understand the need to be conservative.

Answer (score -1):

Look at git-filter-branch at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch and the section 'To remove commits authored by "Darl McBribe" from the history:' there. I have no idea how this is going to work for the resulting code base unless all of these filtered commits are orthogonal to all other other functionality in the resultant code base, such that each can be removed without having any dependencies of later (unfiltered) commits break.

Comment: That doesn't fly because it doesn't remove the changes, just the commits. The idea is a complete exorcism of that person's involvement in the project for legal reasons. Their contributions are poison - even a single byte remaining in any form can be grounds for a lawsuit.

Comment: "NOTE the changes introduced by the commits, and which are not reverted by subsequent commits, will still be in the rewritten branch. If you want to throw out changes together with the commits, you should use the interactive mode of git rebase."